# Learning Optimal Partitions

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, set-partition

Let $f,f_i:[0,1]^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be continuous functions.  Suppose that there are regions $\Omega_i \subset [0,1]^d$ (Compact) such that $f=\sum_i f_i 1_{\Omega_i}$.  Is there a learning algorithm (with proven consistency properties) which selects the optimal $\Omega_i$?

Here, say $k$ is fixed.

Comment: What is a "partion"?

Comment: The set $\{\Omega_i\}_{i=1}^k$ satisfying $\Omega_i\cap \Omega_j = \emptyset $ (if $i \neq j$) and $\cup_i \Omega_i = [0,1]^d$.

Comment: Don't you mean "partition"?

Comment:  I didn't notice at all